# Display more than 3 posts in home page for "Travel Agency" Wordpress Rara Theme

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

for my Wordpress website, I use "Tour Operator" theme, a child theme of "Travel Agency" from Rara Theme (https://rarathemes.com/.
It displays only 3 posts in homepage and I would like to increase it (a multiple of 3 posts, 9 or 12 posts).
Can you tell me what theme 's file I have to modifiy please?
Thanks a lot.
Best regards.
Théo.

Answer (score 0):

If the home page posts are not displaying posts from any custom post type.
You can easily change the number of post from `setting->reading->Blog pages show at most (your number of post)`

[image: Screenshoot of the setting]

Comment: Thanks. My setting is like your but only 3 posts are displayed on haomepage. I think I have to midif a theme file?

Comment: ok so first of check what kind of posts are showing on your home page if it is not a normal blog post then it is a custom post type.
if this is a custom post you need to make one change into your code from where it is displaying. 

You can easily check to find the correct file by installing a plugin called ```which template file```